# What is the meaning of poem 'The Road Not Taken'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, poetry

What is meaning off below lines. I am not able to understand it. Can anyone please explain me.

> Two roads diverged in a wood, and I—
>
> I took the one less traveled by,
>
> And that has made all the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Two roads diverged in a wood, and I —***

This one literally means, in the wood, there was a point at which two paths forked away, implying the times in life you have to choose between your options and make a decision.

***I took the one less traveled by,***

This one literally means I took the one which seemed to be less traveled by passengers, implying a sense of taking risks and going into the unknown.

***And that has made all the difference.***

This line literally means that by going on this path I went through a lot of different things that I wouldn't have gone if I chosen otherwise, implying life makes more sense when you look at it backward!